Building foundations first and adding structures later?
I am buying a home, not exactly a fixer-upper but has several necessary repairs as well as several improvements we'd like to make. Unfortunately we are exceeding our available budget for now, so some of the changes we'll have to defer.
The priciest improvement we'd like to make is adding a garage and attaching it to the house via a mudroom. Two-car garage, fairly basic, some storage but minimal other bells & whistles except for an EV charger.
I know nothing about the process of building something like that from scratch, but what I'm wondering about is whether it be possible to have a concrete foundation poured for the garage and mudroom first (and we'd simultaneously pour/pave a bit of the driveway), and then add the actual structures later when budget allows. We'd use the concrete foundation of the garage as a parking pad for the time being, in that case.
Is that possible? and would it even make sense process/budget-wise?
I am in NoVA/DC area, so some rain/snow, no really extreme temperatures. Frost depth is 24".

Isn't the foundation/pad always poured first and the structure built later?

@gnicko   Usually.  My neighbours brought a small house and move it to the lot.  It was put in place and they had the foundation dug out under the house.  Was quite interesting.

You can do this, but remember any rain/snow will land on the floor/pad, so might want a slight slope for draining.

@isherwood good question! I don't actually know what would be required in this situation. The area where the structures would go is unbuilt right now, just gravel driveway plus lawn, not sure how deep the soil goes before bedrock. Not sure what would be needed for a garage + mudroom, but basically, whichever is necessary for a future structure is what I'm asking about

@gnicko yes, I think so, I mean adding the structures substantially later rather than immediately after


would it even make sense process/budget-wise?

Probably not.  If you were laying some other foundation at the same time, perhaps.  But in this case, you would be bringing out the concrete just for this.  You could do it later without increasing the cost.  Doing it later saves the extra wear for the period of time when there's no building protecting it.
If you just lay down some gravel now, that will help provide a bed for the concrete later.  A layer of big stones (3 or 4) followed by smaller stones (2b) will be good to drive on for now.  Later you can do the concrete and buildings when you can afford it.
The gravel is less subject to damage than concrete and easier to fix (basically add more gravel).
If you want to put in an EV charger, you may want to lay the conduit for that before adding the concrete.  Because if it goes through the floor, you want the concrete around it.  This will be easier if you have the building plans when you put in the conduit (so that you know where the building's walls will be).
One reason why you might want to put the conduit in the floor is if you want the EV charger between the two cars so that you can charge either.
You probably don't want to have empty conduit exposed to the elements for months while you're waiting to put up the buildings, so this favors waiting to do the concrete.
Another reason to wait is that the kind of slab you'd put in for a parking space is different from that for a garage.  You probably want a flat garage.  For drainage purposes, your parking space should have a slope.
There are a couple reasons to wait to do the concrete, and I haven't heard one for doing it now.  As best I can tell, you just want a couple parking spaces and the ability to walk to the door.  Gravel is sufficient for that and it's easier to add a slab to gravel than to change the slab once it's in.  Unless you have some other reason to do it that you haven't stated, my recommendation would be to wait.
All that said, I agree with this answer that it is possible.
Note:  you also mentioned moderate insulation for the garage but no conditioning.  If you're not conditioning a space, there's no reason to insulate it.  You need at least passive condition (e.g. passive solar heat) to make insulation useful.  Insulation slows but does not stop heat transfer.  Therefore, if there's nothing changing the temperature of the space, there's nothing for insulation to do.  A garage will fast assume the outdoor temperature, particularly if you open the doors frequently (to let the cars in or out).  Somewhat of an aside from your main question.  If you have follow up, you may want to check out other questions or post a separate one for that.

Since the plan isn't clear, I'll address three types of foundations separately.
Unprotected or insulated shallow foundations (integrated footings)
If your garage foundation is truly just a slab, possibly with a thickened edge, there's not much to be concerned about. Be aware that your slab's smooth finish will see more weathering that it would if it was sheltered. Also, it'll be slippery when wet or icy.
Insulated shallow foundations (separate footings and foundation walls)
This type of foundation is generally used for conditioned spaces, because the interior of the foundation isn't usually insulated against frost heave. However, you could also insulate the interior, including the slab, then pour the slab. As long as the ground under the slab doesn't freeze hard you should be ok.
Full depth uninsulated foundations (separate footings and foundation walls)
In this case you wouldn't usually have insulation, so an unprotected slab substrate may tend to move with freeze cycles. You could insulate just the slab to help with that. Geothermal heat would keep it from freezing.
You could also just put in the foundation and pour the slab later, using a gravel bed as temporary parking. This would keep your slab shiny and new after you build your garage.

Thanks! So, noob question, then - given my situation (24" frost depth, basic single-floor garage and mudroom - garage probably unheated and moderately insulated, mudroom heated) - which of these is likely necessary?

I don't have anywhere near enough information about your situation to answer that. Please take the [tour].
